# Providing default values for pandas.io.json_normalize

Tags: python, pandas, flatten

I have a list of dictionaries like:

```
dictionary= {'a': 1, 'b':[{'c':2},{'c':3}], 'd' : 'not_relevant_data'}
```

and I want to create a DataFrame like:

```
'a' 'c'
 1   2
 1   3
```

which can be done with `df = json_normalize(data=list_of_dictionaries, record_path = 'b', meta ='a')`.

The problem arises when `'b'` is not present in one of the dictionaries. 
`dictionary = {'a':4, 'd': 'not_relevant_data'}` will result in a a KeyError, but I would like to get a df like:

```
'a' 'c'
 4   None
```

Is there a way of providing a default value in case `record_path` does not exist? Is there a different way to do this?

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in order to get your desired output, you can create a function where you add your wanted behaviour:

```
def add_for_missing(d, record_path, wanted_column='c'):
    if record_path not in d:
        return {**d, record_path: [{wanted_column: None}]}
    return d

json_normalize(data=add_for_missing(dictionary, 'b'), record_path = 'b', meta ='a')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Sorry I was not clear enough. My data consists of many dictionaries in a list - some with, some without 'b' key. I'd like to avoid looping over the list of dicts in python and correcting "by hand".

Comment: I think there is no other way than correcting "by hand" since you want a custom behavior